# kivy app change the font size of the entire application

Tags: python, kivy

I am building a kivy app and I want to add a settings screen that allows the users to change the font size of the entire application (that is, all the text in buttons and labels). I can't find a way to do it unless I manually go over all the buttons and labels and change them one by one. is there a sane way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one or more `NumericProperty` in the `App` class. Then, in your `kv` you can assign the `font_size` as:

```
font_size: app.default_font_size
```

where `default_font_size` is the `NumericProperty`. Note that the loading of such a `kv` will need to be done after the `App` is created (because of the `app` keyword use). A good choice is within the `build()` method of the `App`.

Then any change to the `default_font_size` will be reflected in your GUI.

Comment: Oh my god how much time have I spent on this! tried this solution before but initialized the app only after building the kv file and thus it failed. For anyone reading this in the future, Note the Note!!!
Thank you!